# Why is write duplicating text in parent process?

Tags: c, linux, unix, io, operating-system

I am reading Operating Systems Three Easy Pieces. While working through one of the exercises, I encountered an interesting behavior related to the 'write' system call. The program is as follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() 
{
    int fd = open("./some_file.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 0777);
    int rc =  fork();
    if (rc < 0) 
    {
        printf("Fork failed\n");
        exit(10);
    }
    else if (rc == 0) 
    {
        write(fd, "the sun shines so bright\n", 26);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        int e = write(fd, "it's a cold night outside \n", 36);
        if (e == -1)
        {
            printf("error writing to fd, %s", strerror(errno));
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As the parent process waits for the child process to finish, the output of this program is,

```
the sun shines so bright
it's a cold night outside
```

which is expected. However, if I change the # of bytes to write in child process from 26 to 36,

```
write(fd, "the sun shines so bright\n", 36);
```

the output changes to

```
the sun shines so bright
it's a colit's a cold night outside

_________^ 10 bytes
```

The child process string (the sun shines so bright\n\0) is 26 bytes. The additional 10 bytes are causing this behavior. I have tried different values for the write statement in child process and the behavior is consistent. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: The count needs to match how many bytes are actually in the string you're writing. Giving the wrong number causes undefined behavior. If you increase the count by 10 make sure to add 10 characters to the message.

Comment: `fork()` also returns `pid_t`, **not** `int`.  See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/fork.html

Comment: Take one guess what is stored in memory after the string `"the sun shines so bright\n"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please explain why this is happening?

For `write(fd, "the sun shines so bright\n", 26);` there's only 25 bytes and then the zero terminator that shouldn't be written, but that zero terminator is probably just ignored by whatever you're using to display the file so it "works" (by accident, in a way that would break if you displayed the file a different way and the zero terminator in the middle of the file wasn't ignored).

For `write(fd, "the sun shines so bright\n", 36);` there's still only 25 bytes, then the zero terminator that shouldn't be written, then 10 more bytes of garbage that shouldn't be written. That garbage just happens to be the start of a completely different string, so (due to a combination of luck and undefined behavior) it actually writes "`the sun shines so bright\n`" then the ignored string terminator then "`it's a col`".

For `write(fd, "it's a cold night outside \n", 36);` there's only 26 bytes and then the zero terminator that shouldn't be written, and then 9 bytes of garbage the shouldn't be written. In this case (due to a combination of luck and undefined behavior) I'd assume the garbage just happens to be zeros. I'm honestly surprised that (due to a combination of luck and undefined behavior) it didn't end up writing "`it's a cold night outside \n`" then the ignored zero terminator then "`error wri`".

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. If I add an error check in the child process, I can see it errors out. You are right about the "error wri" output in the parent process. I was not seeing it on my terminal due to the lack of a new line char.